# How to deploy Spark application jar file to Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am currently trying to deploy a spark example jar on a Kubernetes cluster running on IBM Cloud.

If I try to follow these [instructions to deploy spark on a kubernetes cluster](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes), I am not able to launch Spark Pi, because I am always getting the error message:

> The system cannot find the file specified

after entering the code

```
bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://<url of my kubernetes cluster> \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<spark-image> \
    local:///examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

I am in the right directory with the `spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar` file in the `examples/jars` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure `your.jar` file is present inside the container image.

[Instruction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes#cluster-mode) tells that it should be there:

> Finally, notice that in the above example we specify a jar with a
> specific URI with a scheme of local://.  This URI is the location of
> the example jar **that is already in the Docker image**.

In other words, `local://` scheme is removed from `local:///examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar` and the path `/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar` is expected to be available in a container image.

Comment: thanks, I forgot that! I know how to build it, but how can I push it? I tried to execute "./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar -t tag push", but then I get "The push refers to repository [spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar/spark]
Get https:///v2/: http: no Host in request URL"

Can you tell me how and where to push it? Thank you!

Comment: As I see, you are trying to use filename instead of repository address. So, I suspect you have not created correct docker image. As mentioned in the instruction, the Dockerfiles that helps you create correct docker image (docker build . ) can be found in kubernetes/dockerfiles/ directory. After successful build, docker image is located in the local docker storage for images and can be uploaded to remote docker registry with docker push. I guess docker-image-tool.sh just add some specific for spark options to the build-push process.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure this absolute path `/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar` is exists.

Or you are trying loading a jar file in current directory, In this case it should be an relative path like `local://./examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar`.

I'm not sure if `spark-submit` accepts relative path or not.

Comment: thanks, but it also doesnt work with the absolute path to the file

Comment: maybe it's about `spark` itself, try running `bin/spark-submit` only.

Comment: Seems to be installed correctly, I get proposals for parameters etc.

Comment: Add `--verbose` to the original command, Exception details should be useful.

Comment: I get no additional output with verbose :/

Comment: using `./` before the path worked for me!